# In relation to the paragraph 12.7p3 in the C++ Standard, I have the following questions

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, standards, implicit-conversion

1. What are the specific problems that are being avoided with the restrictions imposed by this clause `12.7p3` (see the first part of paragraph below)?
2. In the example shown in `12.7p3` (see below) why `X(this)` is considered defined? Is it because `X` is not in the path `E C D B A` ?

   ```
   struct A { };
   struct B : virtual A { };
   struct C : B { };
   struct D : virtual A { D(A*); };
   struct X { X(A*); };
   struct E : C, D, X {
   E() : D(this),  // undefined: upcast from E* to A*
                   // might use path E* - D* - A*
                   // but D is not constructed
                   // D((C*)this), // defined:
                   // E* - C* defined because E() has started
                   // and C* - A* defined because
                   // C fully constructed
         X(this) { // defined: upon construction of X,
                   // C/B/D/A sublattice is fully constructed
       }
   };
   ```
3. Please find below the start of paragraph `12.7p3`:

> To explicitly or implicitly convert a pointer (a glvalue) referring to
>   an object of class X to a pointer (reference) to a direct or indirect
>   base class B of X, the construction of X and the construction of all
>   of its direct or indirect bases that directly or indirectly derive
>   from B shall have started and the destruction of these classes shall
>   not have completed, otherwise the conversion results in undefined
>   behavior.

Is it correct to say that the set of all direct and indirect bases of `X`, mentioned above don't include `B`, and because of this the code below is well defined, notwithstanding the fact that `Base` is a direct base of `Derived` and has yet not started?

```
struct Base{ Base(Base*); };

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived() : Base(this) {};
};
```

Comment: +1 just for the rare effort of trying to find answers in the standard.

Comment: @PlasmaHH a nice example of good old-fashioned protestant work ethic, looking for the answers in the scripture instead of exclusively with gurus.

Answer (score 6):

> What are the specific problems that are being avoided with the restrictions imposed by this clause 12.7p3 (see the first part of paragraph below)?

The problems have to do with the fact that, at some point, the virtual pointers (to virtual table or virtual base classes) must be initialized for the derived class. This is an initialization that occurs during the "initialization list" (i.e., before the constructor-body begins), usually right after the base class was constructed (e.g., after base class B is constructed, the virtual table pointer and possibly virtual base pointer is set for class X, and then the data members are initialized, and then the constructor's body begins). In general, doing an up-cast before those pointers are initialized will yield undefined behaviour, either because the pointer lookup required cannot be done for a virtual base, or the virtual table pointer will not be set correctly for the virtual functions to be called correctly.

> In the example shown in 12.7p3 (see below) why X(this) is considered defined? Is it because X is not in the path E C D B A ?

Because the base class constructors are called in the order that they appear in the class declaration (i.e., `struct E : C, D, X {`). Because the base classes C and D are both constructed, their common virtual base class A is certainly also constructed. And because `X` does not inherit from class `A`, it means that there is a fully-constructed and unambiguous path when performing the cast from class `E` to class `A` at this point. That is why that line is well-defined.

> Is it correct to say that the set of all direct and indirect bases of X, mentioned above don't include B, and because of this the code below is well defined, notwithstanding the fact that Base is a direct base of Derived and has yet not started?

I'm not sure I follow your explanation, but I can tell you that the code you showed is not well-defined. When calling the constructor of `Base` by casting `Derived* this` to `Base*`, the base-class object in the derived class is not yet constructed, and thus, the cast is undefined.

The only way that this code could make sense is if there were no virtual functions or virtual base classes involved in the hierarchy, in which case, such code would not be needed since the `this` pointer to the base class is already sent, implicitly, to the base-class constructor.

Comment: +1, not sure if worth noting, but in the example from the standard, if the line `D(this)` was rewritten as `D(static_cast<C*>(this))` it would be perfectly defined. The issue arises only as the compiler might decide to use `D`'s base to resolve the location of the `A` subobject.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion on the `Derived : Base` example at the end.  `Base` isn't a "direct or indirect base of `Derived` that directly or indirectly derives from `Base`".  (The first condition is met, it is a base of `Derived`, but it is not derived from itself)

Comment: @Mikael Isn't that correct that any virtual call inside a constructor always points to the member function corresponding  to the object under construction? If this is the case, I don't understand why this clause would be so important to avoid the kind of problem you mentioned in your explanation.

Comment: @BenVoigt Isn't a class always trivially considered to derive directly from itself? (i.e., an object is always a sub-object of itself) I would agree that in this case the code probably works as expected in real life, just because there is no virtual inheritance involved. If Base was a virtual base of Derived, then the code would be undefined behaviour since the cast would technically rely on the base class pointer, which it is not at this point. Since 12.7p3 does not raise that distinction, I'm left with no choice but to make the most conservative assumption.

Comment: @user2337207 Calling a virtual member function in the initialization list before the base class constructor (to which the virtual function is tied) has completed is undefined behaviour, see 12.6.2/13. The point is, virtual table and virtual base pointers are initialized right after the base class constructor has finished, and thus, any use of them (calling a virtual function or casting to a virtual base) is undefined behaviour until that point, regardless of whether the compiler could, in theory, make the call or cast correctly without those pointers. And 12.7/3 takes a conservative position.

Comment: @Mikael: That would make a cast from a class's type to itself an upcast.  But it isn't; it's an identity cast.